# ng-selected not working with ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

ng-selected not working with ng-repeat,in inspect element i can see ng-selected= true and there is selected attribute on option element.my code is as follows and output screenshot is also given below.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
         <label for="">{{diamond.category_id}}</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
         <select ng-model="diamond.category_id" class="form-control">
                 <option  ng-selected="{{diamond.category_id == category.id}}" 
                          value="{{category.id}}"
                          ng-repeat="category in categoryData"
                 >{{category.id}}</option>
          </select>
     </div>
```

Output Link : http://prntscr.com/bfcdwa

Comment: try use `ng-options` .  `<select ng-model="diamond.category_id"     ng-options="category as category for category   in categoryData"> </select>`

Comment: i figured it out thnk you @SSH answer is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by using ng-options

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
     <label for="">{{diamond.category_id}}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
      <select ng-model="diamond.category_id"
              ng-options="category.id  as category.fullName for category in categoryData" 
              class="form-control">
     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item.id for item in categoryData track by item" 
 ng-model="diamond.category_id">
</select>
```

Comment: actually you give me vision

Answer (score 0):

you should do so:

```
  <option  ng-selected="diamond.category_id == category.id" 
                          value="{{category.id}}"
                          ng-repeat="category in categoryData"
                 >{{category.id}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control"
    name="country"
    ng-model="address.country"
    ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries"
    ng-change="address.province = address.country.data; address.province = address.country.data[0];address.city = address.province.data[0]">
```